# How can I send payments from one user to another who isn't known at the time of payment creation?

Tags: node.js, payment

I'm putting together an app where a sender will set a dollar amount they want to pay. My app will receive the money and hold it temporarily. Then once the recipient user decides to claim the money, I send it to them.

I heard from a friend that Stripe Connect did exactly this, however after going through some of the documentation it seems like this might be for paying businesses (instead of regular users). I tried using the Express Payout forms but they have a required field for "Business Website" which definitely won't work.

Can Stripe even do something like this. If so, which Product/API should I be looking into? If not, is there a service that can do this?

UPDATE: I talked to Stripe Support and they said unfortunately they won't be able to support my business model. I've updated the question to exclude Stripe as an assumption.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to run this by Stripe Support at https://support.stripe.com/contact to verify if this fund flow is allowed.

Technically, Stripe Connect and Payments are flexible so I can see how this could potentially work but it all depends on if this is a valid fund flow and Stripe Support would be able to verify that first, and answer the technical side of this too.